# Ruby 2D array of different types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, highcharts

How do i declare a 2D array of type string and int?

I want to do something like this

```
@products.each do |p|
   array = [p.title, p.price]
end
```

But i get an error saying cannot convert string to int

The problem is i can only call f.series() once and i need an array to hold all of my data

```
f.series(:name => 'Product Sales', :data => array)
```

I'm trying to follow this code to create a pie chart

https://github.com/bakongo/highcharts_plugin_sample_graphs/blob/master/app/controllers/graphs_controller.rb

```
def pie_chart
@categories = generate_categories(6)
@numbers = generate_numbers(6)
assoc = []
@categories.each_with_index {|c,i| assoc << [c, @numbers[i]]}

@highchart = HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
  f.title(:text => 'Flowers in Yard')
  f.options[:chart][:defaultSeriesType] = "pie"
  f.options[:x_axis][:categories] = @categories
  f.series(:type => 'pie', :name => 'Flower Presence', :data => assoc)
end

def generate_numbers(number)
   numbers = [rand(number)]
   (1...number).each_with_index {|v, i| numbers << (rand(number)+1)}
   numbers
end

def generate_categories(number)
   cats = ['Sunflower', 'Magnolia', "Rose", 'Lily', 'Tulip', 'Iris']
   cats[0...number]
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ruby you can save different type of the element in the single array like following

```
arr = [1, 1.0, "This is a String", {abc: pqr}, [6]]
#arr[0].class = Fixnum
#arr[1].class = Float
#arr[2].class = String
#arr[3].class = Hash
#arr[4].class = Array
```

So if you want to save array of array like following

```
[["value1", 1.0], ["value2", 2.0]]
```

Use following

```
array = []
@products.each do |p|
  array << [p.title, p.price]
end
```

OR just

```
array =  @products.collect{|p|  [p.title, p.price]}
```

Edited to show the access the 2D Array

```
arr = [["value1", 1.0], ["value2", 2.0]]
#arr[0] = ["value1", 1.0] 
#arr[0][0] = "value1" 
#arr[0][1] = 1.0
#arr[1] = ["value2", 2.0]
#arr[1][0] = "value2" 
#arr[1][1] = 2.0
```